# What are the prerequisites for using Google App Engine with Android?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I am new to Android Application Development and know all the stuff, which is required to build an Application which can use the local resources (databases and all that stuff). I want to build an Application, which will interact with the Application server. And I chose Google App Engine as my Application server. As I am slightly new to this topic, I just want to know, what are the prerequisites for doing both client and server side programming.

I would require to store some data on Google App Engine and interact with the apps with reference to the same.

P.S. I have chosen Java as my language with Google App Engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is any prerequisites for using android with google app engine.
Google App Engine is a PAAS, u can write the server side and it should work irrespective of Android, iPhone or any other device. For data transfer you can use XML or JSON format, see this if u are interested in creating REST services.[Create and Deploy a JAX-RS REST service on Google App Engine](http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.in/2010/02/create-and-deploy-jax-rs-rest-service.html)
For data transfer from server to android device, u can use Google Cloud Messaging [Google Cloud Messaging for Android](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html)

Comment: Actually, I am new to Server Side programming. Can you please provide me a link, where I can get to know about the basic concepts.

Comment: google app engine developer's documentation is a good one https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction

Comment: I am also not familiar with JSP and servlets. I followed the JSP and servlet tutorial from Vogella.com, but It was not much helpful. Can you provide me the link where I can learn about JSP and servlets.

Comment: @CyberGeek you can read "Head first Jsp and Servlets" book. http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfsvlt/

Comment: @CyberGeek see if this is useful http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/06/bootstrap-your-apps-cloud-services-with.html

Comment: Is 'Amazon Web Services' and 'Windows Azure' similar to Google App Engine. I mean can they be used as Backend for an Android application?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I think I have found what I was looking for!